# how to find sum of variable c1+c2+c3 for expression combinations

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

how to find sum of variable `c1 + c2 + c3` for expression combinations:

```
a1 + a2 + a3 + b1 + b2 + b3 + c1 + c2 + c3 == 45
a1 + a2 == 10
b1 + b2 == 3
a3 + b3 == 14
```

then find `c1+c2+c3` by looking it this should give ans like `c1 + c2 + c3 = 18` all variable and >0 integer only I also want to do more combination if possible.

Comment: `Eliminate[{a1 + a2 + a3 + b1 + b2 + b3 + c1 + c2 + c3 == 45, 
  a1 + a2 == 10 , b1 + b2 == 3, a3 + b3 == 14}, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, 
  b3}]`?

Comment: it shows 18 - c2 - c3 == c1 and not this c1+c2+c3=18

Comment: try `Simplify[c1 + c2 + c3, 
 Assumptions -> 
  Eliminate[{a1 + a2 + a3 + b1 + b2 + b3 + c1 + c2 + c3 == 45, 
    a1 + a2 == 10 , b1 + b2 == 3, a3 + b3 == 14}, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2,
     b3}]]`

Comment: What if  i what to find possibility of c1 c2 c3 separately or all variable

Comment: Maybe you require [Reduce](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)? `Reduce[{a1 + a2 + a3 + b1 + b2 + b3 + c1 + c2 + c3 == 45 && 
    a1 + a2 == 10 && b1 + b2 == 3 && a3 + b3 == 14}][[1]]
` gives `c1 == 18 - c2 - c3`

Answer (score 4):

You could also do:

```
y /. ToRules@Reduce[{a1 + a2 + a3 + b1 + b2 + b3 + c1 + c2 + c3 == 45,
    a1 + a2 == 10,
    b1 + b2 == 3,
    a3 + b3 == 14,
    c1 + c2 + c3 == y
    }, {y}]
```

yields 18 (=c1+c2+c3=y)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
eq1 = a1 + a2 + a3 + b1 + b2 + b3 + c1 + c2 + c3 == 45;
eq2 = a1 + a2 == 10;
eq3 = b1 + b2 == 3;
eq4 = a3 + b3 == 14;
```

Then

```
rule = {a1 -> x - a2, b1 -> y - b2, c1 -> z - c2 - c3, a3 -> t - b3};
```

Then

```
Solve[{eq1 /. rule, eq2 /. rule, eq3 /. rule, eq4 /. rule}, {x, y, z, 
  t}]

(*  {{x -> 10, y -> 3, z -> 18, t -> 14}}  *)
```

Done, have fun!